# How to avoid flickering in action bar while showinh and hiding it on scroll

Tags: android, android-listview, tabs, android-actionbar, flicker

i want to scroll up and down the action bar on scroll of listview in android just same as the Google play store app.

I have action bar and tabs below action bar as in Google play store app

I can hide and show the action bar but it flickers while doing this.

Please tell me how to avoid flickering